# PHP script hangs when calling external command from CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script that executes an external bash script to make an SSH connection but even though i am using ssh's move to background (-f) as well as an '&' my PHP script hangs.

Problem line in PHP script

```
system('/usr/local/bin/startProxy 172.16.0.5 9051');
```

I have also tried :

```
system('/usr/local/bin/startProxy 172.16.0.5 9051 &');
```

And the startProxy script is simply :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# startProxy <IP_Address> <Proxy_Port>
#
# Starts an ssh proxy connection using -D <port> to remote system
#
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -f -N -D $2 $1 &
```

Calling the startProxy script from command line works find and the script returns immediately.

When the system() command is run, the called script does run (I can see ssh running via ps), it just never appears to return to the PHP script.
I have run into the same issue when trying to call ssh directly via the system() method as well.

Comment: any error logs?

Comment: does the PHP script hang and complete or hang indefinitely?

Comment: What user does PHP run as? It should not be root and the user may not be authorised to use startProxy if it's shelled?

Comment: Hi Martin, no errors are shown, have added 'error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');' to my test script and nothing output at all.  I should point out that when testing this i am calling the php script from the command line rather than a browser, so any errors should be shown screen with E_ALL set.

Comment: Hi Martin, user running script is myself, so its the same user as when calling the startProxy command directly.  Also have just done another test and can confirm that the startProxy script is exiting but PHP isn't continuing execution. Tested by inserting a sleep timer in startProxy and using ps to check for startProxy actually running, can see it while sleep is pausing the script and it disappeared afterwards, so the script is terminating correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't have any immediate ideas for you. How about what happens if you define a file for the proxy to dump to? `If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.`

Comment: Also try and run other arbitary commands via `system` to see if it is this program or this method that is causing the hang?

Comment: other commands like system('ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2'); don't hang the script.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Martin,

For future self and others, I had to change the system call to

```
system('/usr/local/bin/startProxy 172.16.0.5 9051 2>&1 >/dev/null');
```

and to change the startProxy script to :

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -f -N -D $2 $1 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

before PHP return to the rest of the script!

Anyone able to explain why PHP stops like this if output is not redirected (I presume PHP isn't scanning the command and seeing the redirection part) and also why PHP hangs is i don't include the redirection in the ssh command within startProxy, dispite the fact that both the PHP system call and the ssh command in startProxy where using background options (-f and '&' )

Comment: It is a good practice to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` (and sometimes `stdin`) of a process you launch in background. Otherwise it inherits them from the parent process and shares them with the parent process. This is the cause of your PHP script hanging (it is waiting for the shell script to end).

Comment: Ah, what i don't understand though is that the ssh command within startProxy wasn't inheriting the redirect from the PHP system. PHP hung if I had the redirect in the system call but not directly on the ssh command inside startProxy.